# VBA-List various filenames from folders and subfolders based on different strings

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to list all the files from a folder and subfolder(s) based on a string from a userform into a new workbook. For eg. I am want to input the string as 0200-T1;0201-T12 and I am splitting the string using ";" to search for two or more files which begin with the respective strings. Please have a look at my code and suggest corrections. Currently it only lists the first string from the split array.

```
Sub ListFilesHomolog()
xdir = Usrfrm_JbOrderFiles.Txtbx_Browse2.Value ' define search path
Set mywb = Workbooks.Add
Call ListFilesInFolderHomolog(xdir, True)
End Sub

Sub ListFilesInFolderHomolog(ByVal xFolderName As String, ByVal xIsSubfolders As Boolean)
Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
Dim xFolder As Object
Dim xSubFolder As Object
Dim xFile As Object
Dim rowIndex As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.GetFolder(xFolderName)
On Error GoTo 0
rowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        On Error Resume Next
            fname = xFile.Name
          HomFiles = Split(Usrfrm_JbOrderFiles.txtbx_jbOrdNo2.Value, ";")
          For scount = LBound(HomFiles) To UBound(HomFiles)
            srchTrm = HomFiles(scount) 'value from form
            tst = Split(fname, "-")

            If InStr(UCase(tst(0) & "-" & tst(1)), UCase(srchTrm)) = 0 Then GoTo a: 'skip if string not found
            With mywb
                mywb.Activate
                Worksheets(1).Columns("A:H").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E($A1<>"""";MOD(LIN();2))"
                Worksheets(1).Columns("A:H").FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    With Worksheets(1).Columns("A:H").FormatConditions(1).Interior
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                        .TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
                    End With
                Worksheets(1).Columns("A:H").FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

                Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "File Name" 'file name"
                Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 8).Value = "Link" 'file name"
                Worksheets(1).Cells(rowIndex, 1).Formula = xFile.Name 'file name
                ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(rowIndex, 8), xFile, TextToDisplay:="Open"
                Worksheets(1).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
                ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
            End With
                rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            Next scount
a:
    Next xFile
If xIsSubfolders Then
    For Each xSubFolder In xFolder.SubFolders
        ListFilesInFolderHomolog xSubFolder.Path, True
    Next xSubFolder
End If
Set xFile = Nothing
Set xFolder = Nothing
Set xFileSystemObject = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently exit from your `For scount` loop if the file being looked at does not match the first criteria.

Using your example criteria of `"0200-T1;0201-T12"`, if the filename does not contain the string `"0200-T1"` you exit the loop and never check to see if the filename contains the string `"0201-T12"`.

You need to change

```
        Next scount
a:
    Next xFile
```

to be

```
a:
        Next scount
    Next xFile
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try that out. One more doubt is that how do I know when is the last iteration of the loop (last xFile or last subfolder) in my code above?

Comment: @arkadutta - Why do you need to know when it's the last iteration?  Usually (but, admittedly, not always) anything that needs to be done on the "last" iteration can actually be done after the last iteration finishes, i.e. outside the loop, so I'm just wondering what problem you have that can only be resolved by executing something inside the loop on the last time through it.

Comment: May be I couldn't make it clear, I need something to be executed after the last iteration,  however somehow I am not being  able to find the loop end

Comment: @arkadutta - The loop ends at the `Next` statement.  After the last iteration of your `For Each xFile In xFolder.Files` loop is finished, the code line following `Next xFile` is executed - so you could insert at that point any "perform after the last file" code that you need.

Comment: Well I had tried putting some code after the "next xFile" but the code got executed more than once, which means it is still inside some loop, can you kindly check once more?

Comment: Code placed after `next xFile` will only be executed once (per call of `ListFilesInFolderHomolog`), **after** the last file in the folder is processed.  Code placed after your original call of `ListFilesInFolderHomolog` will be executed once (per call of `ListFilesHomolog`), **after** the last folder is processed.  If you want something processed each time the last file in a folder has been processed, place it after `next xFile` or, if you want something processed only after the last file in the last folder has been processed, place it after the original call of `ListFilesInFolderHomolog`.